# Kotlin returns null on variables whose values are set by annotations

Tags: java, kotlin, appium

I am trying to convert the following piece of code from Java to Kotlin:

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "getStarted")
MobileElement androidElement;
```

What this code does is instead of instantiating the androidElement I use annotations to assign value to this class and I am able to use that variable without having to manually assign a value to it.

In Kotlin however, I have tried to convert this code to its Kotlin equivalent but no matter what variation I try, the variable is never instantiated. I have tried the following in Kotlin:

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "getStarted")
internal lateinit var androidElement: MobileElement

@AndroidFindBy(id = "getStarted")
internal var androidElement: MobileElement? = null
```

My question is, how would I be able to convert this Java code to its Kotlin equivalent?

Comment: Have you tried adding a target as `@field:AndroidFindBy(id = "getStarted")`?

Comment: Have you tried using [`@JvmField`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/index.html)?

Comment: Trying these right now

Comment: @SqueezyMo Do I use that with lateinit?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. But if the expected value is not nullable, I'd go with lateinit.

Comment: @SqueezyMo unfortunately, that does not work, I get a null pointer with or without lateinit

Comment: @Minn I have not tried using JvmField, could you please expound on how I could use this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you called the field decorator at any point in your code?

`PageFactory.initElements(AppiumFieldDecorator(appiumDriver), pageObject)`

This is what actually populates the annotated fields.